# how can I get unique user_id from Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unique

How can I get unique values from column in the table? For example, I have this Products table:

```
user_id  number
1          900
1          400
2          100
2          300
3          200
```

Here I used....

`like so`
Post.order(number: :desc).limit(3).each do |p|    > I got here

```
  user_id number
  1        900
  1        400
  2        300
```

`like so`
Here I want "user_id" not to overlap. like this
f

```
    user_id number
       1      900
       2      300
       3      200
```

Comment: add `distinct` to the query or use group by user_id and sum the number if you want the `numer` column data

Answer (score 0):

As deepak adviced, you might use distinct.

However, I guess you need to get maximum value from all records with the same user_id? Then you need to use sql to group values by user_id and selecting max from it. In Rails that might be like this. I can't tell you that it will work for sure because don't remember the output, believe it's array of hashes, it might throw the error that you're not using some other field:

```
Post.group(:user_id).max(:value)
```

it's SQL equalent:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(value) FROM posts GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: All I want is to rank first, second, and third.